# Set restrictions to HMAC on Apache2 Server in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, tls

I am not entirely sure whether I am at the right place here or not, but I hope one of you can help me with this:
I want to make certain restricions to the TLS CipherSuits that are used by Apache on my Ubuntu server. I do not want the HMAC to be SHA1 but something different, like SHA256 or stronger. I assumed it has to be set in the /etc/apache2/mods-available/ssl.conf in the line with the SSLCiphersuite, but it does not work. I tried this line:

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA:EECDH:EDH+AESGCM:EDH:+3DES:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES:ECDH:AES:HIGH:MEDIUM:!RC4:!SHA1:!SHA:!HMAC-SHA1:!CAMELLIA:!SEED:!aNULL:!MD5:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!DSS:!PSK:!SRP
```

and this as well (a bit shorter)

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
```

But even after arestart, my Webserer still uses HMAC SHA1.
I have also installed Plesk on it, in case this could have an impact.

Can anybody help me on this point?

BR
John

Comment: Hmm... shouldn't you be modifying the config of sites-enabled instead of sites-available?

Comment: As far as I know all files in mods-enabled are pointing towars the config files in mods-available. Just like this: ssl.load -> ../mods-available/ssl.load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself.
The trick is to change the ciphersuits in /etc/nginx/ssl.conf to whatever you like. Note that this config file requires a `;` at the end of each line. I think this is because of the way Plesk manages all services.

Maybe this helps anybody with simillar problems.